# NSWindow - how to know if a window is hidden vs. minimized?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

A NSWindow can be hidden via `orderOut:` or minimized.

How can I distinguish between the two? `isVisible` returns 0 in both cases.

Comment: `-isMiniaturized` looks exactly like what you want.

Comment: isMiniaturized returns the same value regardless of orderOut. How can I know if a window is both hidden and minimized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `-isMiniaturized` isn't working for you, you can manually keep track of the window's miniaturization status by setting up your own status flag that you update when the window is minimized/de-minimized, using either of the following methods:

- Set up a window delegate that implements [`windowDidMiniaturize:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowDidMiniaturize%3a) & [`windowDidDeminiaturize:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowDidDeminiaturize%3a)
- Set up an observer for the window notifications, [`NSWindowDidMiniaturizeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWindowDidMiniaturizeNotification) & [`NSWindowDidDeminiaturizeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWindowDidDeminiaturizeNotification).

Comment: So the answer is basically, "you can't, you have to track that state yourself". Accepted :)